# How to open a rendered RDL report in a new tab in MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rdl

I just figured out how to render my RDL report to pdf file but it's currently in the temporary folder. The next step should be for it to open in a new window or tab for viewing. I tried many solutions but nothing seems to be working.

Here's my current code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("printDCF")]
    public IHttpActionResult printDCF(int controlFormDetailID)
    {
        try
        {
            ApiResult apiResult = new ApiResult();
            var reportData = ControllerLogic.GetReportData(controlFormDetailID);
            generateReport(reportData);

            return Ok(apiResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult generateReport(List<DocumentControlFormPrintResult> reportData)
    {
        string RptPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AngularViews/forms/dcf/report/DCF_Report.rdl");
        LocalReport rpt = new LocalReport();

        rpt.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", reportData));

        rpt.ReportPath = RptPath;
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        Export(rpt, filePath);      
        rpt.Dispose();

        System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult result = new System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "dcf_print.pdf",
        };

        return result;
    }

    public string Export(LocalReport rpt, string filePath)
    {
        string ack = "";
        try
        {
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;

            byte[] bytes = rpt.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            return ack;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ack = ex.InnerException.Message;
            return ack;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, I tried myself this code working fine for me, it useful for you

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Data/OpenPDF")]
    public HttpResponseMessage OpenPDF()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        string filePath = @"D:\PDF\pdf-test.pdf";
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        }
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue(System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames.Inline)
        {
            FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How does Filename work? When I click the download icon in pdf viewer the filename is the same as the url generated by the window.URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: The File Name property  you can assign the your own file name@Elbert John Felipe

Comment: Sorry. But where do I set it?

Comment: I can modified the answer, FileName  get using the file path string. It's useful for u, i think @Elbert John Felipe

Comment: Oh but I used window.URL.createObjectURL. Bare in mind that I didn't save the file in a physical location so there is no filepath but only a GUID url.

Comment: you want to set the Guid in  the filename correct ? are you passing the guid in API Parameter?. @Elbert John Felipe